# Access 2010 - VBA Cargar Datos tipo Memo en una caja de texto de un informe. Espacio Insuficiente

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Para cargar unos datos en un informe de Access, uso el código VBA siguiente:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

Call Acceso_Informacion
Dim basica As DAO.Database
Dim tabla_ejemplo As DAO.Recordset
Dim Texto As String

Set basica = CurrentDb
Set tabla_ejemplo = optica.OpenRecordset("Principal_Tabla", dbOpenSnapshot)

tabla_ejemplo.MoveFirst

Texto = tabla_ejemplo.Fields(2).Value


Texto1.Value = Texto

End Sub
```

La idea es llenar una Textbox con datos de una tabla de Access. En principio el método funciona. Se evita el uso de macros incrustadas y todo queda fijado en código. Pero hay un problema que no puedo subsanar fácilmente. El tamaño de la TextBox ha de ser variable para que, dependiendo del tamaño del texto a poner ahí, se haga más o menos grande. Así, si se da el caso, el textbox puede llegar a ocupar varias páginas, o bien sólamente unas líneas.

¿Cómo se podría hacer esto? ¿Hay alguna manera de alargar tanto el textbox como largo sea el texto para que aparezca todo bien claro y legible en el informe?

Gracias por anticipado!

Comment: Sí necesitas mostrar datos, no es recomendable que lo hagas en un textbox, a menos que vayas a editar ese dato, lo mas recomendable sería que lo hagas en gridviews o aunque sea en labels.

Comment: En la vista Diseño del informe, si seleccionas el textbox, en la pestaña de formato debería haber una propiedad que se llama **autoextensible**. Esta propiedad btiene o establece si el control especificado se ajusta verticalmente de forma automática para imprimir o vista previa de todos los datos que contiene el control. [información aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-cangrow-property-access). ¿Has probado con eso a solucionar tu problema?

Comment: Excelente! La propiedad "Autoextensible" era la solución. ¿Sólo se puede poner en "propiedades" o se puede introducir en código VBA con algún TextBox.Autoextensible= True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la vista Diseño del informe, si seleccionas el textbox, en la pestaña de formato debería haber una propiedad que se llama **autoextensible**. Esta propiedad obtiene o establece si el control especificado se ajusta verticalmente de forma automática para imprimir la vista previa de todos los datos que contiene el control.

La versión VBA de esta propiedad se llama **CanGrow.**. Es una propiedad booleana, es decir, solamente admite True o False.

> [Propiedad TextBox.CanGrow
>   (acceso)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-cangrow-property-access)